# Putting an element inside Svelte Component

Tags: javascript, svelte

What does putting an element inside Svelte Component mean?
Eg. this code:

```
    const target = document.createElement('div');
    //  render the component in the new element
    const sample = new Sample({ target });
```

Like, here, in the given linked code, author is doing that:
https://github.com/rspieker/jest-transform-svelte/blob/master/example/test/Sample.spec.js#L8

What does this do? Is it putting Svelte component inside a div? Is it a Svelte syntax to put the element inside the constructor of the Svelte component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that snippet is initializing the Svelte component named `Sample` and rendering it within the `target` div. The `target` property of a Svelte component constructor's options parameter is the only required property.

For more information, check out [Svelte's components documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#Client-side_component_API).

Answer (score 2):

It is the place where in your document the component will be rendered. Normally you would use a very specific location like `body` or a div with a certain id.

In this case however you are not actually rendering a page but merely testing a component so it doesn't matter where the `div` is.

You can find more info on testing with Jest here https://jestjs.io/